# When to create a custom NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I've been playing about with the `NSNotificationCenter` and I've been wondering when you would use your own custom notification center rather than the `defaultCenter`? And what would the advantages of this be?

Forgive my ignorance, but it seems like I could get along quite happily just using the `defaultCenter` and nothing else, but I want to make sure I am not missing something vital.

Comment: Legit question, I've always use *defaultCenter* without minding it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple documentation is vague, and it just states that usually a programmer wouldn't need to create a new one:

> Each running Cocoa program has a default notification center. You typically don’t create your own. An NSNotificationCenter object can deliver notifications only within a single program.

Full source: [NSNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

However every notification center can handle a network of notifications, distinguished by name and object. When you add an observer you typically call the method in some way like this:

```
[center addObserver: self selector: @selector(observe:) name: @"observe" object: someObject];
```

And when you post a notification you can specify the object:

```
[center postNotificationName: @"observe" object: someObject];
```

This way say that you use N names and M objects, you can handle N*M distinguished notifications. I think there is no need to use two notification centers. Theoretically if you have finished all names you can create another one using alloc+init, but I hardly see how it can actually turn out handy.

Also consider that notification center is often used when there are two objects that do not own a direct pointer to each other (otherwise why not simply calling a method on it?), due to avoid complicated bindings (specially when you use a lot of xib files), so having an unique notification center object is very handy.

If instead you use a notification center got with allot+init, then you must ensure that all the communicating objects have a pointer to that notification center, and this would add some complexity. All notification center's power would be wasted.

Answer (score 8):

Although it's used heavily in AppKit via the `defaultCenter` singleton accessor, at it's heart, NSNotificationCenter is really just a "generic decoupling mechanism." Allowing you to `alloc/init` your own instances of it is just an expression of that generic-ness. If you wanted to use it for something else, you could.

To illustrate with a somewhat absurd example, think of it this way: NSDocument has a `windowControllers` accessor that returns a specific, blessed, important instance of NSArray that contains references to all the window controllers specific to that document. That said, NSArray is just a "generic list data structure". Just because there exists this special instance of it with a specified purpose doesn't mean it might not be useful to reuse NSArray for your own purposes. Both NSArray and NSNotificationCenter provide generic data structures/building blocks, specific instances of which are used in blessed "occupations" around AppKit, but both of which could be useful on their own.

The primary use case I've seen for creating standalone instances of NSNotificationCenter is when you want to run multiple instances of some complex subsystem on multiple threads in parallel and not have them potentially get confused by cross-thread notifications. In this case, the general pattern is to allocate one NSNotificationCenter per thread. This compartmentalizes the notifications for each network of objects to a single thread. This will generally be required if observers pass `nil` for the object parameter intending to listen to *all* notifications with a given name, regardless of source.

All that said, I concede that, in my experience, making private instances of NSNotificationCenter is pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)

> > > If your app uses notifications extensively, you may want to create and post to your own notification centers rather than posting only to the default notification center. When a notification is posted to a notification center, the notification center scans through the list of registered observers, which may slow down your app. By organizing notifications functionally around one or more notification centers, less work is done each time a notification is posted, which can improve performance throughout your app.